# Drag and Drop the whole div container. (Move Pop-up Modal dialog box)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

Here I have a Modal pop-up. I want to make the modal draggable. And also I want the "Ok" button to be in green on hover and "cancel" should be in red on hover. I's it possible to do it in single css class?

```css
.hidModal{
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 500;
    opacity:2;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
}

.windowModal {
    width: 400px;
    top:15%;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background:rgba(255, 204, 153,0.2);
    z-index: 501;
    opacity:0.5;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#ffe6cc, #ffa64d);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffe6cc, #ffa64d);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#ffe6cc, #ffa64d);
}

#winMod{
    position: relative;
}

.windowModal:hover{
    opacity: 1.0;
    }


.closeMod {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 4px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.closeMod:hover { 
    background: #aaaaaa;
    color: #ff0022;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bttnMod {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.bttnMod:hover { 
    background: #00d9ff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="hidModal">
    <div id="winMod" class="windowModal">
    
        <div  style="margin-top: 1%;">
        <input class="closeMod" type="button" name="Close" value="X" style="width:8%" onclick="winClose();" >
            
        <div style="margin-top: 1%;">
            <label class="label lblwidth1">&nbsp;</label>
            <input class="bttnMod" type="button" name="OK" value="OK" onclick="clickok();" tabindex="1" style="width:50">
            <input class="bttnMod" type="button" name="Cancel" value="Cancel" tabindex="2" style="width:55" onclick="winClose();">
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I tried some posible ways. But it didn't work. Those were in  jQuery. But I dont have much knowledge in that. So please help me to solve this.
Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: here your not added javascript code.

Comment: @chandukomati I didn't use JavaScript to make that draggable. I just tagged to get some help from JS side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives the exact output.

```js
dragElement(document.getElementById("parnt"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
.hidModal{
 position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 500;
    opacity:2;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
}



.windowModal {
   width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background:rgba(255, 204, 153,0.2);
    z-index: 501;
    opacity:0.5;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#ffe6cc, #ffa64d);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffe6cc, #ffa64d);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#ffe6cc, #ffa64d);
}

#parnt{
   position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 40%;
    bottom: 85%;
    left: 15%;
    right: 50%;
}

.windowModal:hover{
 opacity: 1.0;
 }


.closeMod {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 4px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.closeMod:hover { 
 background: #aaaaaa;
 color: #ff0022;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.bttnMod {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.bttnMod:hover { 
 background: #00d9ff;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="hidModal">
  <div id="parnt">
    <div id="winMod" class="windowModal">
    
     <div  style="margin-top: 1%;">
     <input class="closeMod" type="button" name="Close" value="X" style="width:8%" onclick="winClose();" >
      
     <div style="margin-top: 1%;">
      <label class="label lblwidth1">&nbsp;</label>
      <input class="bttnMod" type="button" name="OK" value="OK" onclick="clickok();" tabindex="1" style="width:50">
      <input class="bttnMod" type="button" name="Cancel" value="Cancel" tabindex="2" style="width:55" onclick="winClose();">
     </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This works as I expected.

Answer (score 2):

For the draggable part, if you're using JQuery there's the [Draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) property.

```
$("#your-modal").draggable();
```

You can also specify which part of the modal to assign the property to (in this example, the modal's header).

```
$("#your-modal").draggable({ handle: "#your-modal-header" });
```

As for the buttons, you can change their background color and add some transition animation with the `:hover` selector. Though I believe it is best to handle their classes separately as shown below.

```
ok-button:hover {
  background-color: green;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

cancel-button:hover {
  background-color: red;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

Snippet:

```css
.hidModal {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 500;
    opacity:2;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
}

.windowModal {
    width: 400px;
    top:15%;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background:rgba(255, 204, 153,0.2);
    z-index: 501;
    opacity:0.5;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#ffe6cc, #ffa64d);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffe6cc, #ffa64d);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#ffe6cc, #ffa64d);
}

#winMod {
    position: relative;
}

.windowModal:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
}


.closeMod {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 4px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.closeMod:hover { 
    background: #aaaaaa;
    color: #ff0022;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bttnMod {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.ok-button:hover { 
    background-color: green;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.cancel-button:hover { 
    background-color: red;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="your-modal" class="hidModal">
    <div id="winMod" class="windowModal">
        <div style="margin-top: 1%;">
            <input class="closeMod" type="button" name="Close" value="X" style="width:8%" onclick="winClose();">
            <div style="margin-top: 1%;">
                <label class="label lblwidth1">&nbsp;</label>
                <input class="ok-button bttnMod" type="button" name="OK" value="OK" onclick="clickok();" tabindex="1"
                    style="width:50">
                <input class="cancel-button bttnMod" type="button" name="Cancel" value="Cancel" tabindex="2" style="width:55"
                    onclick="winClose();">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $("#your-modal").draggable(); 
</script>
```

---

**EDIT:**

For a solution without having to include JQuery/JQueryUI (that is, pure Javascript), you can follow the below snippet for reference. Added some comments as it's a considerable amount of extra lines of code compared to the above snippet.

```js
// Get your modal by it's ID and declare it as a variable
var modal = document.getElementById('your-modal');
// Declare variables for X and Y positions of your modal and mouse movements
var posX, posY, mouseX, mouseY;

// Triggers when the user clicks and holds the mouse down on your modal
modal.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
    posX = this.offsetLeft;
    posY = this.offsetTop;
    mouseX = event.clientX;
    mouseY = event.clientY;

    // Triggers when the user moves the mouse around as it's holding the click down
    this.addEventListener('mousemove', moveElement, false);

    // Triggers when the user lets go of the mouse
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
        modal.removeEventListener('mousemove', moveElement, false);
    }, false);

}, false);

// Function in charge of repositioning the modal
function moveElement(event) {
    this.style.left = posX + event.clientX - mouseX + 'px';
    this.style.top = posY + event.clientY - mouseY + 'px';
}
```

```css
.hidModal {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 500;
    opacity: 2;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
}

.windowModal {
    width: 400px;
    top: 15%;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(255, 204, 153, 0.2);
    z-index: 501;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#ffe6cc, #ffa64d);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffe6cc, #ffa64d);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#ffe6cc, #ffa64d);
}

#winMod {
    position: relative;
}

.windowModal:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
}


.closeMod {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 4px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.closeMod:hover {
    background: #aaaaaa;
    color: #ff0022;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bttnMod {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.ok-button:hover {
    background-color: green;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.cancel-button:hover {
    background-color: red;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="your-modal" class="hidModal">
    <div id="winMod" class="windowModal">
        <div style="margin-top: 1%;">
            <input class="closeMod" type="button" name="Close" value="X" style="width:8%" onclick="winClose();">
            <div style="margin-top: 1%;">
                <label class="label lblwidth1">&nbsp;</label>
                <input class="ok-button bttnMod" type="button" name="OK" value="OK" onclick="clickok();" tabindex="1"
                    style="width:50">
                <input class="cancel-button bttnMod" type="button" name="Cancel" value="Cancel" tabindex="2"
                    style="width:55" onclick="winClose();">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Should I use that "<script src=...>". Is there any posibilities using css anf javascript.

Comment: Added a pure Javascript solution in case you do not want to use JQuery, see my edit above. Also added some comments to explain what's going on as it is quite a few extra lines of code compared to the `draggable()` solution.

Comment: Really thank you so much. It works, but I want the orange div should move. But here the whole thing is getting dragged.  I tried changing the id which is "id=winMod" in javaScript, but it didn't work. Should I do more changes?

Comment: I really would like to up vote, but due to lack of reputation. It says I need 15 Rep to up vote. I'm trying to increase it. But badges are getting increased.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the plugins that allow you to make the div draggable.
But for the different background color I'm not sure if it's doable with the same class name.

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#winMod" ).draggable();
  });
```

```css
.hidModal{
 position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 500;
    opacity:2;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
}

.windowModal {
   width: 400px;
   top:15%;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background:rgba(255, 204, 153,0.2);
    z-index: 501;
    opacity:0.5;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#ffe6cc, #ffa64d);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffe6cc, #ffa64d);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#ffe6cc, #ffa64d);
}

#winMod{
 position: relative;
}

.windowModal:hover{
 opacity: 1.0;
 }


.closeMod {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 4px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.closeMod:hover { 
 background: #aaaaaa;
 color: #ff0022;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.bttnMod {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.bttnMod:hover { 
 background: #00d9ff;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="hidModal">
    <div id="winMod" class="windowModal">
    
     <div  style="margin-top: 1%;">
     <input class="closeMod" type="button" name="Close" value="X" style="width:8%" onclick="winClose();" >
      
     <div style="margin-top: 1%;">
      <label class="label lblwidth1">&nbsp;</label>
      <input class="bttnMod" id="OK" type="button" name="OK" value="OK" onclick="clickok();" tabindex="1" style="width:50">
      <input class="bttnMod" id="Cancel" type="button" name="Cancel" value="Cancel" tabindex="2" style="width:55" onclick="winClose();">
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Should I use this "<script src=..". Is there something else like css or javascript to do this? And may I know why do we use those two code sorce!

Comment: Answering to the second question, you use `<script src=...` to call for an external code libraray, the same way you would call (for example) any CSS or Javascript file. In this case, we're calling JQuery and JQueryUI. Both are Javascript libraries with tons of functionalities that make it much easier to do some things that would be tedious to do on plain Javascript. This is a great example, as you can simply make an element draggable using `$("#element").draggable();` instead of having to write a lengthy Javascript function to achieve the same result.

Comment: Ohh, now I understood. I should use this library src to make this `$("#element").draggable();` work.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example in plain JavaScript. Click and move the header to move the popup itself. It will stay inside the parent container.

```js
var offset = [0, 0];
var isDown = false;

var headerElement = document.getElementById("#PopupHeader");
var popupElement = document.getElementById("#PopupMainDiv");
if (headerElement && popupElement) {

  // On MouseDown event callback
  var mouseDown = function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    isDown = true;
    if (popupElement) {
      popupElement.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove);
      popupElement.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp);
      offset = [
        event.clientX,
        event.clientY
      ];
    }
  }

  // On MouseUp event callback
  var mouseUp = function() {
    isDown = false;
    if (popupElement) {
      popupElement.removeEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove);
      popupElement.removeEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp);
    }
  }

  // On MouseMove event callback
  var mouseMove = function(event) {
    if (isDown) {
      if (popupElement.parentElement) {
        let newX = offset[0] - event.clientX;
        let newY = offset[1] - event.clientY;
        const rect = popupElement.getBoundingClientRect();
        const boundaries = 
        popupElement.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
        const x = Math.min(
            Math.max(boundaries.left, rect.left - newX), 
            boundaries.right - rect.width
          ),
          y = Math.min(
            Math.max(boundaries.top, rect.top - newY), 
            boundaries.bottom - rect.height
          );
        popupElement.style.left = `${x}px`;
        popupElement.style.top = `${y}px`;
        offset = [
          event.clientX,
          event.clientY
        ];
      }
    }
  }
  headerElement.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown);
}
```

```css
.PopupLayered {
  background-color: rgba(40,40,40,0.7);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center
}

.PopupMainDiv {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid #dddddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  color:white;
}

.PopupHeader {
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: #333333;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  height: 25px;
  cursor: move;
  color: black;
}

/* Popup title span */
.PopupHeader span {
  width: 90%;
  float: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  margin: 0.3em 0.3em;
}

/* Popup close button */
.PopupHeader button {
  color: white;
  background-color: #cc0000;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 20px;
  margin: 0.1em 0.2em;
  height: 20px;
}

  /* Popup close button hover */
.PopupHeader button:hover {
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Popup {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: gray;
  width:400px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="#PopupLayered" class="PopupLayered">
  <div id="#PopupMainDiv" class="PopupMainDiv">
    <div id="#PopupHeader" class="PopupHeader">
      <span>Click and drag the header!</span>
      <button type="button">x</button>
    </div>
    <div id="#Popup" class="Popup">
        <img src="http://www.alleycat.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/FELV-cat.jpg" width="450"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```